# Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "Appliances": syntax error (code 1):

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin, syntax

I have 5 tables in SQLITE when I try to compile it says "Syntax error" But I can't find any syntax error in the code.

**Here is my Code**

```
override fun onCreate(db: SQLiteDatabase?) {
        var ClothTable = "CREATE TABLE $Cloth (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,Description TEXT ,IMAGE BLOB)"
        var DairyTable = "CREATE TABLE $Dairy (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,Description TEXT ,IMAGE BLOB)"
        var EATable = "CREATE TABLE $ElectricalAppliances (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,Description TEXT ,IMAGE BLOB)"
        var FoodTable = "CREATE TABLE $Food (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,Description TEXT ,IMAGE BLOB)"
        var VegetableTable = "CREATE TABLE $vegetable (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,Description TEXT ,IMAGE BLOB)"

        db?.execSQL(ClothTable)
        db?.execSQL(DairyTable)
        db?.execSQL(EATable)
        db?.execSQL(FoodTable)
        db?.execSQL(VegetableTable)


    }
```

**Error is :**

```
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "Appliances": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE Electrical Appliances (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,Description STRING ,IMAGE BLOB)
```

Comment: You cannot have space in table names

Answer (score 2):

I guess you have declared the variable ElectricalAppliances like this:

```
val ElectricalAppliances = "Electrical Appliances"
```

as a table name but the space is not allowed. 
Change it to:

```
val ElectricalAppliances = "[Electrical Appliances]"
```

The name must be surrounded with square brackets [ ] or backticks ` (ascii code 096).

Comment: Thanks alot brother , It works I did'nt know before that sqlite not accpet white spaces

Comment: No white spaces for table names, columns, indexes etc.

Comment: If this answer solved your problem consider accepting it.